# react-native iOS Photos features

Tags: image, react-native

I am new to React-Native. With help from this forum and others, I was able to create a small App with images loading from Firebase in ListView. I have a question ... is it possible to implement features that are in iOS Photos?

What I am trying to do is, when a user touches and holds on an image in ListView, I would like to popup the image with options (Like, Favorite) in the image below. Appreciate any help.

[image: iOS Photo]

Update:
I changed the code like this:

```
render() {
      return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

            <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)} enableEmptySections={true} removeClippedSubviews={true} style={styles.listview}> </ListView>
               </View>             
            );
}

_renderItem(item) {
    return (
            <ListItem item={item}/>
            );
 }

 ListItem.js

 class ListImages extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <MenuContext style={{flexDirection: 'row', padding: 5}}>
            <Menu onSelect={value => alert(`Selected number: ${value}`)}>
            <MenuTrigger>
            <Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={{width: 400, height: 250}} source={{ uri: this.props.item.name }} />
            </MenuTrigger>
            <MenuOptions>
            <View width={400} height={600} style={styles.listimagecontainer}>
            <Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={{width: 350, height: 500}} source={{ uri: this.props.item.name }} />
            </View>
            <MenuOption value={1} text='Test' />

            </MenuOptions>
            </Menu>
            </MenuContext>
            );
   }
}
```

Images in the ListView are displaying ok. When I click on any image, new view opens up with the image. But the next image in the ListView overlays on the view hiding more than half the view. What am I doing wrong here ? I also want to display the image in full with correct aspect ratio. Appreciate any help.

UPDATE with suggested code:

```
            <MenuContext style={{flexDirection: 'row', padding: 5}}>
            <Menu onSelect={value => alert(`Selected number: ${value}`)}>
            <MenuTrigger>
            <Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={{width: 400, height: 250}} source={{ uri: this.props.item.name }} />
            </MenuTrigger>
            <MenuOptions>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Like`)} text='Like' />
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Share`)} text='Share' />
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} text='Delete' />
            </MenuOptions>
            </Menu>
            </MenuContext>
```

Here is screen shot:

[image]

What I am trying to do is, ListView displays images at 400x250. When the user clicks on the image, show a larger image of the same (say 325x500 like in iOS) and present the user with options say - like, share, delete. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Look up `react-native-popup-menu`, where in your case, each item in your `Listview` (each image) would be a `menuTrigger`. You are welcome.

Comment: Updated my question - used react-native-popup-dialog. But image is not displayed.

Comment: I am not aure about popup dialog, but i use popup menu and it works fine

Comment: I couldn't follow react-native-popup-menu. Can you please give me a small working example. Thanks !

Comment: There is one on their site and it is very simple. Why you could not follow it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ... I didn't click on the link to their example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151633/discussion-between-cnk2343-and-khalil-khalaf).

Comment: Updated code to use react-native-popup-menu. But view in menu is overlayed with next image in ListView.

Comment: Can you show a print screen? And it looks like you have two images, hence why you see two? `MenuTrigger` is the component you want the user to click on (in your case it is the image), and `MenuOptions` is a "list" of the things you want to popup for example three `Text`: "Like" "Share" "Delete" .. etc. But it is clear that you have the same image both under trigger and under options

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two images, hence why you see two.

`MenuTrigger` is the component you want the user to click on (in your case it is the image).

`MenuOptions` is a "list" of the things you want to popup for example three `Text`: "Like" "Share" "Delete" .. etc.

But it is clear that you have the same image both under trigger and under options. What you want is something like this:

```
<MenuContext style={{flexDirection: 'row', padding: 5}}>
    <Menu onSelect={value => alert(`Selected number: ${value}`)}>
        <MenuTrigger>
            <Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain} style={{width: 400, height: 250}} source={{ uri: this.props.item.name }} />
        </MenuTrigger>
        <MenuOptions>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Like`)} text='Like' />
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Share`)} text='Share' />
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} text='Delete' />
        </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
</MenuContext>
```